# I want to get rid of words with exact pattern in character vector using regular expressions but don't know how

Tags: r, regex

I have this vector

```
names <- c("wazzzap12waaazzzaaaaapffffm12323", "hell223231", "musssaaaa225")
```

So I want to remove words saving for numbers in vector's elements which have at least three "z" letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may use `grep` with `invert = TRUE`.  Specify the regex as `z` with repeats of 3 or more with `{}`

```
grep("z{3,}", names, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
[1] "hell223231"   "musssaaaa225"
```

---

Or use `str_subset` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(names, "z{3,}", negate = TRUE)
[1] "hell223231"   "musssaaaa225"
```

#### Update

If we want to remove the non-numbers only from those having 'z' repeats

```
i1 <- grep("z{3,}", names)
names[i1] <- gsub("\\D+", "", names[i1])
```

-output

```
> names
[1] "1212323"      "hell223231"   "musssaaaa225"
```

Comment: Yeah. It's pretty close but I would like to save numbers from the first one :(

Comment: @ЕгорИванов can you show the expected output

Comment: `names <- c("1212323", "hell223231", "musssaaaa225")`
`names`

Comment: @ЕгорИванов please check the update